# Android: What is the lifetime of a ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

What is the lifetime of a ContentProvider in Android? After `onCreate()` is invoked, will the ContentProvider persist unconditionally for the lifetime of the process?

My ContentProvider manages a list of records, but only 1 is designated "active" and will be accessed by different applications a lot. I was wondering if it's safe to cache the index of this active record in memory as a member of my ContentProvider to speed up lookup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> After onCreate() is invoked, will the
>   ContentProvider persist
>   unconditionally for the lifetime of
>   the process?

Yes.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @ElvisDukaj: Probably not. Also, while I *think* that statement is still true, please bear in mind that this answer is from 2010, which is ancient Android history.